# Ternary operator returning false. Why?

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
guessed_letter = []
word_to_guess = "hair"
letter_holder = []
word_to_guess.split("").each do |letter|
  letter_holder << (guessed_letter.include?(letter)) ? letter : "_"
end
letter_holder.join('')
```

I have the word `"hair"` being split, with nothing in `guessed_letter` array. The ternary operator returns `false`. Shouldn't it return the underscore for each of the letter?

Answer (score 2):

Restructure your code like this:

```
guessed_letter = []
word_to_guess = "hair"
letter_holder = []
word_to_guess.split("").each do |letter|
  letter_holder << (guessed_letter.include?(letter) ? letter : "_")
end

letter_holder.join('')
# => "____"
```

**What is the issue with original code?**

Look at following line:

```
letter_holder << (guessed_letter.include?(letter)) ? letter : "_"
```

Following the order of precedence, this code actually means:

```
( letter_holder << (guessed_letter.include?(letter)) ) ? letter : "_"
|____________________________________________________| |____________|
                 |                                            |
                 .                                            .
    (Element getting inserted first)               (followed by ternary op on array)
```

Hence you get `false` all the time as `guessed_letter.include?(letter)` is always `false` (since `guessed_letter` is an empty Array)

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is explainable. The ternary operator has a very low priority of execution and therefore Ruby thinks that you add the boolean expression to the `letter_holder` array.

try this:

`letter_holder << ((guessed_letter.include?(letter)) ? letter : "_")`